# Storing Age numbers expressed in decimals in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have an age column that is currently varchar because i cannot figure out how to define it correctly.

the ages look like the following samples:

```
.03   /   .3  /  1.33  /  20
```

i tried Decimal (4,2) but then i get something like 82.00! which i dont want.
I want under 1 to look like 0.2 or .2, or .25
I want age 82 to be just 82 and age 5 to be just 5.

do I have to do this in php after the case or is there a way to store the numbers without the extra 0's.

storing as varchar displays them correctly but does not allow for the proper search.

Comment: This is presentation-level stuff. It is like wondering which brand of screwdriver to buy if you want your furniture to be dark brown — a different job altogether. :) Let MySQL do what it's good at, remembering the exact value; let the presentation layer do what it needs to do, format the value for the user.

Comment: just store the birth date as `date`, then do the `0.2` or whatever in php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How you store a number and how you format it when printing it are not mutually exclusive things. Storing numbers as strings is about the worst thing you can do. `Decimal(4,2)` tells MySQL to store the number with up to 2 digits of precision for the integral part of your number and up to 2 digits of precision for the fractional part. This says nothing about how those digits can be printed, however. For example `printf("%d", 1.01)` gives you `1`. Whereas `printf("%.2f", 1.0123)` gives you `1.01`.

PHP has several functions that can assist with formatting such as `sprintf`, and `number_format`, not to mention `Intl`'s `NumberFormatter` for i18n.

If all you want is to truncate the right-most 0s from the number when printing it you can try something like `rtrim($number, '0.')`.

```
echo rtrim(1.00, '0.'); // 1
echo rtrim(1.10, '0.'); // 1.1
echo rtrim(1.11, '0.'); // 1.11
echo rtrim(10.01, '0.'); // 10.01
```

The only edge case you have to watch out for here is if the number is `0` you will end up with an empty string.

Comment: what will rtrim do to a (null) value? will it just leave it null or will it become 0?

Comment: `NULL` as a string is always just an empty string. `rtrim()` has no effect in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Storing age as a varchar will lead to unexpected behaviour for instance when you `ORDER BY age` in a query.

Use the right types that map to your data.

ON displaying numbers with/without decimal places, use your application language (PHP) to perform this function.